# Array storage upon prompt

Tags: javascript, arrays, prompt

I asked a similar question earlier but I wasn't clear, I'm learning how to ask the right questions on here. I am prompting a user to enter a number which will be the size of the array and then looping through to have them fill the array with numbers until they reach the size they declared earlier. My question is how to properly store the array with the user's input.

```
function getNumber() {

      var el = document.getElementById("demo");

      // Get the user's input and convert it to a number
      var size = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the size of the array"),10);


        var entries = parseInt(prompt("Enter an integer"),10);

        var userInput = new Array();
        while (entries < size){
             var entries = parseInt(prompt("Enter an integer"),10);
             userInput.push(entries);
             userInput = entries.split(" ");

        }

      // Store the user's input to our global variable
      //userInput[] = entries; 

      // Set up a string that will become the output.

      //display iterations
      el.textContent = userInput[entries];

    }
```

Comment: you're clobbering userInput array here `userInput = entries.split(" ");`

Comment: Here: `userInput = entries.split(" ");` you override your `userInput` value.

Comment: If the user entered a size of `3` and then decided to input numbers bellow `3` then the loop will go for as long as the user keep entering number less than 3!

Comment: I noticed that when the screen only printed out the number I entered. What would be a good way to approach fixing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the code slightly different:

```
function getNumber() {

    var el = document.getElementById("demo");

    // Get the user's input and convert it to a number
    var size = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the size of the array"),10);

    // array that will store user input
    var userInput = [];
    while (userInput.length < size){
         var entries = parseInt(prompt("Enter an integer"),10);
         userInput.push(entries)
    }
  //join array element with a space to display
  el.textContent = userInput.join(" ");

}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see where I went wrong, thank you for the help.